# Server IBM WebSphere Failed to start at local machine

Tags: java, websphere

I have installed WebSphere v8.5 on my local machine. After installation it was running fine then I shutdown my server and restarted server again but server failed to start

Following is error log:

```
Could not find the main class: for.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: for
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: for
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
Could not find the main class: for.  Program will exit.
```

My environment specs are:
Eclipse photon
Java 8

Comment: It looks like something is trying to launch the class `for` which I'm guessing is a typo somewhere. How are you launching?

Comment: I tried to launch from eclipse.

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of your Eclipse environment, including the run configuration?